# RegEx with preg_match to find and replace a SIMILAR string

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pattern-matching, preg-replace

I am using regular expressions with `preg_replace()` in order to find and replace a sentence in a piece of text. The `$search_string` contains plain text + html tags + `&nbsp;` elements. The problem is that only sometimes the `&nbsp;` elements convert to white space on run time, making it difficult to find and replace using `str_replace()`. So, I'm trying to build a pattern that is equal to the search string and will match anything like it which contains, or does not contain the `&nbsp;` elements;

For example:

```
$search_string = 'Two years in,&nbsp;the company has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S. Plus,&nbsp;in&nbsp;April, <a href="site.com">ClassPass</a> acquired its main competitor,&nbsp;Fitmob.';
```

`$pattern` = `$search_string`(BUT IGNORE THE `&nbsp;` elements in the subject)

```
$subject = "text text text text text". $search_string . "text text text text text";
```

Using [A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string), I've tried:

```
     $pattern = '`^/(?!\&nbsp;)'.$search_string.'`';
     $output = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement_string,$subject);
```

The end result will be that if the $subject does contains a string that is like my `$seach_string` but without the `&nbsp;` elements, it will still match and replace it with `$replacement_string`

**EDIT:**

The actual values:

```
$subject = file_get_contents("http://venturebeat.com/2015/11/10/sources-classpass-raises-30-million-from-google-ventures-and-others/");

 $search_string = "Two years in,&nbsp;the company has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S. Plus,&nbsp;in&nbsp;April, ClassPass acquired its main competitor,&nbsp;Fitmob."; 

$replacement_string = "<span class='smth'>Two years in,&nbsp;the company has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S. Plus,&nbsp;in&nbsp;April, ClassPass acquired its main competitor,&nbsp;Fitmob.</span>";
```

Comment: IGNORE or convert to space?

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work. May be I'm wrong - the str_replace() fails not because of &nbsp; but something else. It's worth mentioning that the $subject is actually a whole web page. Any other suggestions? It seems I need a regex pattern that will match any string in the subject which has, say 90% similarity to the $search_string ?

Comment: Please, could you give the link to the source page and the real search and replacement strings?

Comment: $subject = file_get_contents("http://venturebeat.com/2015/11/10/sources-classpass-raises-30-million-from-google-ventures-and-others/"); $search_string = "Two years in,&nbsp;the company has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S. Plus,&nbsp;in&nbsp;April, ClassPass acquired its main competitor,&nbsp;Fitmob."; $replacement_string = "<span class="smth">Two years in,&nbsp;the company has expanded to 35 cities, five of which are outside the U.S. Plus,&nbsp;in&nbsp;April, ClassPass acquired its main competitor,&nbsp;Fitmob.</span>";

Comment: that replacement string has the `&nbsp;` encoded into it. look to my answer below

Comment: What's determining where you add the "smth" span class?

Comment: also, you're using double quotes twice, ie in the replacement string and around the replacement string.

Comment: I add the span class around all replacement strings

Comment: It's single quotes inside, I changed it. That's not the mistake though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94932/discussion-between-madivad-and-user3857924).

Comment: Would it make anything easier to first do a `$subject = str_replace( '&nbsp;', ' ', $subject );` and the do the search when it only contains ordinary spaces?

Comment: I've tried that but it still doesnt work. For some reason, it's able to find and replace the string just before the &nbsp; and the one after. But not when you combine them. This made me think it is related to &nbsp; ..

Answer (score 0):

Not a very efficient way of doing it but it should workout for you,

```php
preg_replace('Two.*?years.*?in.*?the.*?company.*?has.*?expanded.*?to.*?35.*?cities.*?five.*?of.*?which.*?are.*?outside.*?the.*?U\.S\..*?Plus.*?in.*?April.*?ClassPass.*?acquired.*?its.*?main.*?competitor.*?Fitmob\.', '<span class=\'smth\'>$0</span>', $subject);
```