# Find and replace string in HTML using PHP DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom, domparser, findandmodify

How do you find and replace a string in html page using the native PHP DOM Parser?

Example string to find: `"the <a href='site.com'>company</a> has been growing for the past 5 months";`

The parent is a full HTML page for example and the immediate predecessor of that string can be a `<div>` or `<p>` for example..

There is no id or class to that element. Is it still possible to find and manipulate it ?

There is nothing to identify the string or its immediate predecessor. Only the exact string, i.e. sequence of characters that the $search_string consists of.

Thanks!

EDIT:

$string_to_replace = `"the <a href='site.com'>company</a> has been growing for the past 5 months";`

$replacement_string = `"<span class='someClass'>the <a href='site.com'>company</a> has been growing for the past 5 months";</span>`

Comment: Which string do you want to replace with what?

Comment: In the example above, you do not search for the contents of a DOM element, but rather a text string. If you want to modify `<a href ... </a>` you could use PHP DOM, but not to search for `"the <a href='site.com'>company</a> has been growing for the past 5 months"`. Use a string search/replace for that or a regexp search/replace

Comment: Please see the EDIT. Thanks for clarifying. I've been trying to use str_replace() with little success. Also, people say you should not parse html with regex(which is needed for some replacements). Can you please have a look at this question I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671497/regex-with-preg-match-to-find-and-replace-a-similar-string

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems to span part of a node with child nodes, I would use a replace like this:

```
// Text in $html
$find  = "the <a href='site.com'>company</a> has been growing for the past 5 months";
$find_len = strlen( $find );
$start = strpos( $html, $find );
if ( $start !== false ) {
    $html = substr( $html, 0, $start )
        . '<span class="someClass">' . $find . '</span>'
        . substr( $html, $start + $find_len );
}
```

I do not have time to test it properly, but it might point you in the right direction.

PHP DOM would be excellent to change the href attribute of element `a` or it's contents (*company*). It should also work if $find is the full contents of a `<div>`-element